# Zuul unable to route to application registered in eureka server

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am developing a Microservice were I am trying to use the Zuul proxy to route through the services. But for some reason Zuul unable to route to the app registered in eureka.
I have tried increasing hystrix and Zuul timeout but nothing working

Exception Thrown

> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error    at
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198)
> ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.10.RELEASE.jar:2.2.10.RELEASE]

Zuul application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    hostname: localhost

ribbon:
  eureka:
    enabled: true

zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 5000000
    socket-timeout-millis: 5000000
  prefix: /api
  routes:
    game:
      path: /game/**
      serviceId: game
    trend:
      path: /trend/**
      serviceId: trend
```

Here I have two Microservices called "game" and "trend" both are registered in eureka service, but not able to navigate to applications through Zuul proxy.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Some research I found that Ribbon, Zuul are in maintenance mode and we won't get any new version and spring also came up with alternative for Ribbon, Zuul etc. Please refer this link for [spring alternative](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode) for load balancing, proxy server etc

And for this issue I used spring cloud gateway instead of Zuul which is the alternative provided by spring

Required Dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now the application yml of proxy server looks like

```
server:
  port: 8082

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
      routes:
        - id: game
          uri: lb://game
          predicates:
            - Path=/game/**
        - id: trend
          uri: lb://trend
          predicates:
            - Path=/trend/**

eureka:
  client:
    serviceURL:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```